# How do I change Kat's costume?

Tags: gravity-rush-2

After putting Gravity Rush 2 off for a few months, the addition of a 2B costume piqued my interest enough to finally start playing. That said, how do I *wear* the 2B costume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once Syd gives you the Camera after arriving in Jirga Para Lhao, you will be able to change costumes via photo mode.

To do this, simply open the Camera by pressing up on the D-pad. Once in photo mode, pressing circle will open the costumes menu. From there, you can put on any costume you've already unlocked, including the 2B costume.

Comment: can the costumes be used outside of Camera Mode and worn during normal gameplay? ie like the School Girl and DLC costumes of the previous game?

Comment: @Memor-X yes, I played the entire game as 2B